# returning reference of formal parameter

Tags: c++

Please easy go on me if this is the very basic question.

returning reference from the function, i could see some benefits like. Here is the pseudo code.

```
int myarr[] = { .....  }

int & myfunction(int index)
{
  return myarr[index]
}

myfunction(1) = 20;  // sets the value to myarr[1].
```

I tried with the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int & topper (int & x, int & y)
{
  return (x>y)?x:y;
}

int main()
{
  int a=10, b=20;
  int c;
  c=topper(a,b);
  cout <<"Topper "<<c<<endl;
  c=100;
  cout <<" a value is "<<a<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Question:

My expectation is to print `100` for variable `a`.   I am passing reference of `a` to `topper()` functions, and returns the same reference of `a`, and assign to `c`.

I'm sure some main point i am missing that  when we declare `int c`, it should not be a different memory location, rather it should point to return   the `c` value into different location but we have to make a reference.

Comment: `c` is an `int`. Thus, `c` cannot be an alias to an `int`.

Comment: `c` is a separate variable from `a` and `b`. You want `int &c = topper(a, b);`. (Even then this won't print `100` since `c` would be a reference to `b` and not `a`.)

Answer (score 2):

> and returns the same reference of 'a', and assign to 'c'.

Yes, you're returning `b` (not `a`) by reference, but you're assigning it to `c` **by value**, so you could change code to:

```
int & c = topper(a, b);
cout << "Topper " << c << endl;
c = 100;
cout << " b value is "<< b << endl;
```

Comment: `b` is being returned by reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've fixed the statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Lot of confusion in your question.

But if you are trying to alias the variable c 
to point to topper between a and b, try something like:

`int& c = topper(a,b);`

now c is a reference to whatever the topper returns and 
by changing c, you change the variable returned by topper.

Comment: Can u be bit specific on "Lot of confusion in your question". Not sure if i have missed something?.

Comment: your sentence construction is very poor in the question!

Comment: didn't you understand the question?

Comment: may be i would suggest to edit the question, and get it approved.

Comment: "rather it should point to return the c value into different location" - what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
int &c = topper(a, b);
```

instead of

```
c=topper(a,b);
```

as `c` is a `int` variable.